# Codeigniter doesn't take value from input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter:
I have in my view 
`<input type="text" name="code" style="width:310px;">`

 My controller 
`$code = $this->input->get('code');`

 and after i call a function from my models:

`$this->model->add($code);`

The problem is codeigniter don't take value in controller(i make a test with `$this->model->add('342432');` and it's works. So i think the problem is between view and controller.

 Has anybody a solution? Thanks!.

Comment: taking in consideration all the comments below, I am assuming it has to do with your routing perhaps your `base_url` or `site_url` are not set correctly. I guess its a bit tough to pinpoint where the error is unless you provide us with more information. Can you post your form HTML and your controller method code as well?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon form submit method.

From your code: `$code = $this->input->get('code');` it is `get`.

If you want form with `post` method, use

`$code = $this->input->post('code');`

Comment: My form is `<form id="custom_add" method="get">` so the `get` it's right.

Comment: And i have near that code `<input type="text" name="name" value="">` and this it's works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using get method in Codeignitor make your

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
```

In your config.php file

```
$config['allow_get_array'] is FALSE(default is TRUE), destroys the global GET array.
```

Comment: In my `config.php` is `$config['allow_get_array']  = TRUE;`.

Answer (score 0):

In View

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>/conteroller/method" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="code" style="width:310px;"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" > 
</form>
```

In conteroller

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $result =  $this->model_name->add($code);
    print_r($result);//to check the output
}
```

**Note** :

1. to use `base_url()` function, in `config/autoload.php`

   ```
       $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
   ```
2. In conteroller load model in `__construct`

   ```
       public function  __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->library('session');
           $this->load->model('Model_name');//Ex: Product_Model
       }
   ```